# accessing ViewController buttons within a BluetoothManagerDelegate class

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, bluetooth

So I have just started working with XCode (v7.3) using the Swift language (v2.2), and I am trying to write a single page app that will connect to a targeted BLE device by pushing a button.

I followed a short tutorial on the Core Bluetooth framework on the following website: http://hatemfaheem.blogspot.com/2014/12/how-would-you-scan-for-nearby-ble.html

which had me create the following class structure:

```
class BLEManager{
    var centralManager:CBCentralManager
    var bleHandler:BLEHandler
    init() {
        self.bleHandler = BLEHandler()
        self.centralManager = CBCentralManager(delegate: self.bleHandler, queue: nil
    }
}

class BLEHandler : NSObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate {
    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    func CentralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
        var status:String
        switch(central.state) {
        case .PoweredOn
            status = "Powered On"
            //ble_show()
        case .PoweredOff
            status = "Powered Off"
            //ble_hide()
        }//Note: several cases have been omitted to reduce length
        print(status)
    }
}

var bleManager = BLEManager()
```

After inserting those class definitions and declaring an instance of the BLEManager class inside the ViewController class of my ViewController.swift file, I can see the strings "Powered On" and "Powered Off" displayed in the console as I turn the bluetooth on and off on my iPhone while running the app.

The issue is that I get an error when I call the functions in the above code named "ble_show()" and "ble_hide" (which is why they are commented out). I assume the issue is because these functions are a member of the overarching ViewController class, and you cant just call those functions from inside the nested class: BLEHandler.

The ble_show() and ble_hide() functions simply set the "hidden" flag for a button to reveal it to the user. I want these buttons to become available only when the user has their bluetooth turned on. So the BLEHandler class needs to access these buttons that are declared in the ViewController class somehow, but I dont seem to understand how to do that. I tried moving all my function declarations and UIButton declarations inside the BLEHandler class but XCode really did not like it when I did that.

Part of my problem is that I am learning about Swift, XCode, and the Core Bluetooth framework all at the same time, so if anyone could explain how to accomplish what I am attempting as thoroughly as possible that would be very helpful. I am use to programming in an environment with a simple main() function rather than using a class as a main() (which is how I am currently treating the ViewController class).

If I understand correctly, the CBCentralManagerDelegate is registering some part of my code to an event which calls my CentralManagerDidUpdateState() member function whenever a change in bluetooth status occurs. But how can I tell my ViewController to do something when these events occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By separating the Bluetooth manager from your view controller (which is a good design), you can't directly update items in your view controller.  You can use NSNotification or a protocol/delegate to notify your view controller of the Bluetooth state change.

Since there may be many objects that are interested in Bluetooth events, I would use NSNotification in this case.

In your ViewController class, you can register an observer for a particular notification:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()

    notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(ViewController.bluetoothChanged(_:)), name: "bleStateChange", object: nil)
}

@objc func bluetoothChanged(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let status = notification.userInfo["statusString"] as? String {
        print("Bluetooth status = \(status)")
    }
}
```

In your `BLEManager` you need to post the notification:

```
func CentralManagerDidUpdateState(central: CBCentralManager) {
    var status:String
    switch(central.state) {
        case .PoweredOn
            status = "Powered On"
            //ble_show()
        case .PoweredOff
            status = "Powered Off"
            //ble_hide()
    }//Note: several cases have been omitted to reduce length
    print(status)
    let notificationCenter = NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter()
    let userInfo = ["statusString":"powered off","centralState":central.state.rawValue] as [String:AnyObject]
    notificationCenter.postNotificationName("bleStateChange", object: nil, userInfo: userInfo)
}
```

Comment: So I've added the code you provided and its producing a few errors. It wants me to put an '!' after 'userInfo' on the line: `if let status = notification.userInfo["statusString"] as? String {` and it is having an issue with  'aDict' (use of unresolved identifier) on the line: `notificationCenter.postNotificationName("bleStateChange", object: nil, userInfo: aDict)`. Since I dont really understand what is going on in this code it would be helpful to provide some details on what is going on here

Comment: I think I figured it out now. I replaced 'aDict' with userInfo (declared on the line above) after I saw that it was an unused dictionary and now I am able to get the behavior that I wanted through a switch statement in the bluetoothChanged() func. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Sorry, that was a cut/paste error from my Playground.